# Changing indices of a sum (Basic question)

Tags: summation

I was working through some proofs and it came to a point where I had to change the index of a sum which started as sigma (from k=0 to n-1)

Substituting in i=k+1

So that means, my k=0 would become i=1

But does that mean I also have to increase the n-1 +1 as well, so my new sum would become
Sigma (from i=1 to n) ?

Usually I've dealt with infinite sums, so this issue obviously never came up to me since +/- to infinity is still infinity.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It's exactly that. You even may continue to call $k$ the index, since it's a bound variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must keep the same number of terms in your sum.